# Android webview with anchors

Tags: android, webview, anchor

I am working with a webview and would like to open a link which contains an anchor e.g:

http://uk.search.yahoo.com/mobile/s;_ylc=X1MDMjE0MjQ3ODk0OARfcgMyBGZyMgNzYS1ncARncHJpZAMEbl9ncHMDMTAEb3JpZ2luA3VrLnNlYXJjaC55YWhvby5jb20EcG9zAzEEcHFzdHIDBHF1ZXJ5A3lhaG9vBHNhYwMxBHNhbwMx?ei=UTF-8&_intl=GB&_lang=en-gb&_tsrc=yahoo&_sep=fp&r=web_filter&p=yahoo&fr2=sa-gp#sc_appsearchTab=reviews

On the webview it does not go to the reviews anchor? It just goes to the url without anchor.

I have a WebViewClient with my webview and none of the methods (onPageStarted, onPageFinished) which I override pick up the selection to the anchor page (i.e. reviews)? I select the review link (tab) and it highlights but with out going to that page/anchor?

Using Android browser or Dolphin HD they do not have a problem with the anchor?

Is there something which I need to enable with regards to anchors and a webview?

Answer (score 0):

I had such problem when my WebView was placed on ScrollView, in that case anchors didn't work. Check it.

Comment: Not using ScrollView, so not related.